# Can we perform a live migration between two different Kafka version from onprem to cloud using Kafka Mirror?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We have a use case to perform kafka migration lively, as per our understanding its better to do sync across the same Kafka version using Kafka mirror and then do the upgrade

have any one performed across different kafka versions it may pose problems as per my understanding. For e.g between 2.10 and 3.7.0

Comment: I think you want to say: from kafka 2.1 (not 2.10) to 3.7